# Flutter A build function returned null.StreamBuilder<dynamic>

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I keep getting this error but i cant seem to figure which part is returning null, i even tried just returning an empty container just in case, im not sure where i am going wrong, it usually shows this error when there is no data in firestore

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/model.dart';

class BookScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  book createState() => book();
}

class book extends State<BookScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  String userId;

  checkDatabase() {
    var docSnapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('bookings')
        .where('customer', isEqualTo: userId)
        .snapshots();

    return docSnapshot;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            bottom: TabBar(
              labelColor: Colors.black,
              indicatorColor: Color(0xff008d4b),
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  text: "Upcoming",
                ),
                Tab(text: "Cancelled"),
                Tab(text: "Past"),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('My Bookings',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 20,
                )),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[100],
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: checkDatabase(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          if (snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) {
                            return Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Consumer<MyModel>(
                                    builder: (context, myModel, children) {
                                  userId = myModel.customer;

                                  return Container(
                                      child: Container(
                                          child: Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/sunbird_white.png",
                                    width: 300,
                                    height: 80,
                                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                  )));
                                }),
                                SizedBox(height: 25),
                                Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                      "You currently dont have \n any upcoming stays at our Hotels",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                    )))
                              ],
                            );
                          } else if (snapshot.data.documents.isNotEmpty) {
                            return Container(width: 0, height: 0);
                          }
                        }
                      })),
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        child: Container(
                            child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/sunbird_white.png",
                      width: 300,
                      height: 80,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ))),
                    SizedBox(height: 25),
                    Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                          "You currently dont have \n any cancelled stays at our Hotels",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                        )))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        child: Container(
                            child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/sunbird_white.png",
                      width: 300,
                      height: 80,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ))),
                    SizedBox(height: 25),
                    Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                          "You currently dont have \n any past stays at our Hotels",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                        )))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the error

```
A build function returned null.
The offending widget is:
  StreamBuilder<dynamic>
Build functions must never return null.
To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return
"Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return
"Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  StreamBuilder<dynamic> 
lib\bookings.dart:65
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

...........................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Share with use your error :)

Comment: i have added it, it usually shows this error when there is no data in firestore

Answer (score 0):

This problem when you didn't customize your stream builder so you need to add the type of data that will return in <> after StreamBuilder

i.e  StreamBuilder
Here I told the data that I get is String type
Try It like that

Comment: when i put <String> after stream builder, all the parts i wrote snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty, the document part is red and i get an error which says The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try importing the library that defines 'documents', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'documents'.dartundefined_getter